Kotlin's kaptGenerateStubsKotlin fails every other day
I have been tearing my hair out maintaining a project I wrote in Kotlin.
Basically - it uses EBean, which itself uses Kapt to generate some code.
The problem I have is that, literally, every other build this breaks. I build my project once every few days as I run it through gradle ./gradlew run ....
When it breaks, I fiddle around with the versions a bit and it seems to fix itself. Namely - it's been the Kotlin version I've been consistently bumping and it has seemed to resolve the issue every now and then.
I've done this at least 10 times so far in the past year, and it's driving me insane.
Here is the error:
> Task :kaptGenerateStubsKotlin FAILED
e: java.lang.IllegalAccessError: superclass access check failed: class org.jetbrains.kotlin.kapt3.base.javac.KaptJavaCompiler (in unnamed module @0x65012184) cannot access class com.sun.tools.javac.main.JavaCompiler (in module jdk.compiler) because module jdk.compiler does not export com.sun.tools.javac.main to unnamed module @0x65012184
        at java.base/java.lang.ClassLoader.defineClass1(Native Method)
        at java.base/java.lang.ClassLoader.defineClass(ClassLoader.java:1018)
        at java.base/java.security.SecureClassLoader.defineClass(SecureClassLoader.java:150)
        at java.base/java.net.URLClassLoader.defineClass(URLClassLoader.java:524)
        at java.base/java.net.URLClassLoader$1.run(URLClassLoader.java:427)
        at java.base/java.net.URLClassLoader$1.run(URLClassLoader.java:421)
        at java.base/java.security.AccessController.doPrivileged(AccessController.java:714)
        at java.base/java.net.URLClassLoader.findClass(URLClassLoader.java:420)
        at java.base/java.lang.ClassLoader.loadClass(ClassLoader.java:593)
        at java.base/java.lang.ClassLoader.loadClass(ClassLoader.java:526)
        at org.jetbrains.kotlin.kapt3.base.KaptContext.<init>(KaptContext.kt:55)
        at org.jetbrains.kotlin.kapt3.KaptContextForStubGeneration.<init>(KaptContextForStubGeneration.kt:38)
        at org.jetbrains.kotlin.kapt3.AbstractKapt3Extension.contextForStubGeneration(Kapt3Extension.kt:278)
        at org.jetbrains.kotlin.kapt3.AbstractKapt3Extension.analysisCompleted(Kapt3Extension.kt:157)
        at org.jetbrains.kotlin.kapt3.ClasspathBasedKapt3Extension.analysisCompleted(Kapt3Extension.kt:87)
        at org.jetbrains.kotlin.cli.jvm.compiler.TopDownAnalyzerFacadeForJVM.analyzeFilesWithJavaIntegration$invokeExtensionsOnAnalysisComplete(TopDownAnalyzerFacadeForJVM.kt:104)
        at org.jetbrains.kotlin.cli.jvm.compiler.TopDownAnalyzerFacadeForJVM.analyzeFilesWithJavaIntegration(TopDownAnalyzerFacadeForJVM.kt:114)
        at org.jetbrains.kotlin.cli.jvm.compiler.TopDownAnalyzerFacadeForJVM.analyzeFilesWithJavaIntegration$default(TopDownAnalyzerFacadeForJVM.kt:77)
        at org.jetbrains.kotlin.cli.jvm.compiler.KotlinToJVMBytecodeCompiler$analyze$1.invoke(KotlinToJVMBytecodeCompiler.kt:256)
        at org.jetbrains.kotlin.cli.jvm.compiler.KotlinToJVMBytecodeCompiler$analyze$1.invoke(KotlinToJVMBytecodeCompiler.kt:247)
        at org.jetbrains.kotlin.cli.common.messages.AnalyzerWithCompilerReport.analyzeAndReport(AnalyzerWithCompilerReport.kt:115)
        at org.jetbrains.kotlin.cli.jvm.compiler.KotlinToJVMBytecodeCompiler.analyze(KotlinToJVMBytecodeCompiler.kt:247)
        at org.jetbrains.kotlin.cli.jvm.compiler.KotlinToJVMBytecodeCompiler.compileModules$cli(KotlinToJVMBytecodeCompiler.kt:87)
        at org.jetbrains.kotlin.cli.jvm.compiler.KotlinToJVMBytecodeCompiler.compileModules$cli$default(KotlinToJVMBytecodeCompiler.kt:43)
        at org.jetbrains.kotlin.cli.jvm.K2JVMCompiler.doExecute(K2JVMCompiler.kt:165)
        at org.jetbrains.kotlin.cli.jvm.K2JVMCompiler.doExecute(K2JVMCompiler.kt:50)
        at org.jetbrains.kotlin.cli.common.CLICompiler.execImpl(CLICompiler.kt:104)
        at org.jetbrains.kotlin.cli.common.CLICompiler.execImpl(CLICompiler.kt:48)
        at org.jetbrains.kotlin.cli.common.CLITool.exec(CLITool.kt:101)
        at org.jetbrains.kotlin.incremental.IncrementalJvmCompilerRunner.runCompiler(IncrementalJvmCompilerRunner.kt:463)
        at org.jetbrains.kotlin.incremental.IncrementalJvmCompilerRunner.runCompiler(IncrementalJvmCompilerRunner.kt:62)
        at org.jetbrains.kotlin.incremental.IncrementalCompilerRunner.doCompile(IncrementalCompilerRunner.kt:477)
        at org.jetbrains.kotlin.incremental.IncrementalCompilerRunner.compileImpl(IncrementalCompilerRunner.kt:400)
        at org.jetbrains.kotlin.incremental.IncrementalCompilerRunner.compileNonIncrementally(IncrementalCompilerRunner.kt:281)
        at org.jetbrains.kotlin.incremental.IncrementalCompilerRunner.compile(IncrementalCompilerRunner.kt:125)
        at org.jetbrains.kotlin.daemon.CompileServiceImplBase.execIncrementalCompiler(CompileServiceImpl.kt:657)
        at org.jetbrains.kotlin.daemon.CompileServiceImplBase.access$execIncrementalCompiler(CompileServiceImpl.kt:105)
        at org.jetbrains.kotlin.daemon.CompileServiceImpl.compile(CompileServiceImpl.kt:1624)
        at java.base/jdk.internal.reflect.DirectMethodHandleAccessor.invoke(DirectMethodHandleAccessor.java:103)
        at java.base/java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:578)
        at java.rmi/sun.rmi.server.UnicastServerRef.dispatch(UnicastServerRef.java:360)
        at java.rmi/sun.rmi.transport.Transport$1.run(Transport.java:200)
        at java.rmi/sun.rmi.transport.Transport$1.run(Transport.java:197)
        at java.base/java.security.AccessController.doPrivileged(AccessController.java:714)
        at java.rmi/sun.rmi.transport.Transport.serviceCall(Transport.java:196)
        at java.rmi/sun.rmi.transport.tcp.TCPTransport.handleMessages(TCPTransport.java:598)
        at java.rmi/sun.rmi.transport.tcp.TCPTransport$ConnectionHandler.run0(TCPTransport.java:844)
        at java.rmi/sun.rmi.transport.tcp.TCPTransport$ConnectionHandler.lambda$run$0(TCPTransport.java:721)
        at java.base/java.security.AccessController.doPrivileged(AccessController.java:400)
        at java.rmi/sun.rmi.transport.tcp.TCPTransport$ConnectionHandler.run(TCPTransport.java:720)
        at java.base/java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:1144)
        at java.base/java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:642)
        at java.base/java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:1583)


FAILURE: Build failed with an exception.

* What went wrong:
Execution failed for task ':kaptGenerateStubsKotlin'.
> A failure occurred while executing org.jetbrains.kotlin.compilerRunner.GradleCompilerRunnerWithWorkers$GradleKotlinCompilerWorkAction
   > Internal compiler error. See log for more details

* Try:
> Run with --stacktrace option to get the stack trace.
> Run with --info or --debug option to get more log output.
> Run with --scan to get full insights.

* Get more help at https://help.gradle.org

Deprecated Gradle features were used in this build, making it incompatible with Gradle 8.0.

You can use '--warning-mode all' to show the individual deprecation warnings and determine if they come from your own scripts or plugins.

See https://docs.gradle.org/7.5/userguide/command_line_interface.html#sec:command_line_warnings

BUILD FAILED in 1s

And here are my current parameters:
java -version

java version "17.0.10" 2024-01-16 LTS
Java(TM) SE Runtime Environment (build 17.0.10+11-LTS-240)
Java HotSpot(TM) 64-Bit Server VM (build 17.0.10+11-LTS-240, mixed mode, sharing)

./gradlew -version                                                           ✔  base   

------------------------------------------------------------
Gradle 7.5
------------------------------------------------------------

Build time:   2022-07-14 12:48:15 UTC
Revision:     c7db7b958189ad2b0c1472b6fe663e6d654a5103

Kotlin:       1.6.21
Groovy:       3.0.10
Ant:          Apache Ant(TM) version 1.10.11 compiled on July 10 2021
JVM:          17.0.10 (Oracle Corporation 17.0.10+11-LTS-240)
OS:           Mac OS X 13.2.1 aarch64

Some of my build.gradle:
dependencies {

    // query bean generation
    kapt 'io.ebean:kotlin-querybean-generator:13.11.0'
    implementation 'io.ebean:ebean:13.11.0'
    implementation 'io.ebean:ebean-migration:13.6.0'
    implementation 'io.ebean:ebean-querybean:13.11.0'
    testImplementation 'io.ebean:ebean-test:13.11.0'
}

tasks.withType(org.jetbrains.kotlin.gradle.tasks.KotlinCompile).all {
    kotlinOptions {
        jvmTarget = "17"
    }
}

plugins {

    id 'org.jetbrains.kotlin.jvm' version '1.9.20'
    id "org.jetbrains.kotlin.kapt" version "1.9.20"

    id 'com.github.ben-manes.versions' version '0.28.0'
    id 'io.gitlab.arturbosch.detekt' version '1.22.0'
    id('io.ebean') version '13.11.0'
    id "com.google.protobuf" version "0.9.1"
}

apply plugin: 'java'
apply plugin: 'application'
apply plugin: 'jacoco'

One thing I don't understand - why doesn't this consistently build? Why is the build process so seemingly un-deteministic? The same pinned versions should result in working software all the time - I don't understand what's changing for that to change. I never explicitly update anything on my machine in between these runs.

Looking through my commit history - the second-to-last time I fixed this issue was on April 26. There, I went from Kotlin 1.6.20 -> 1.7.21 and ebean 13.10.0 to 13.20.0. This involved bumping the Gradle version from 7.4 to 7.5 as well.

The latest change I did was bump Kotlin from 1.7.21 to 1.9.20 and reverting back the ebean to 13.11.0 (I actually don't remember why I reverted, it doesn't make much sense to me - but I was fiddling to get it to work)

The latest fix that worked for me was to add this:
kapt {
    keepJavacAnnotationProcessors = true
}

As per https://kotlinlang.org/docs/kapt.html#keep-java-compiler-s-annotation-processors
